# WebApp makes JAVA use +30GB of Virtual Memory

Tags: java, tomcat, optimization, out-of-memory, cas

Firstable sorry for my bad english, I saw like thousands of post in this website and others trying to find some solution to this issue.

I have to optimize one server who is consuming a lot of Virtual Memory and a big % of CPU using Tomcat 8.0.30 and CAS-server. When I look with the command "top" the display shows me the process java using 32,2G minimum. I already cloned the VM where the server was and safely tried almost everything I saw on internet.

When I start the Tomcat java takes 6-7GB instantly and after that keep increasing during half minute until reach at least 32GB.

My heap size parameters are: Xms&Xmx=2048M Xss=400m XX:MaxPermSize=128M

My catalina.out shows the following issues:

```
04-Apr-2016 11:43:09.276 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [cas] appears to have started a thread named [scheduler_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. S tack trace of thread:  java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568) 

04-Apr-2016 11:45:52.746 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web applica tion [cas] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread: 

15-Apr-2016 08:21:30.384 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks La aplicación web [cas_theother] creó un ThreadLocal con clave del tipo [com.codahale.metrics.ThreadLocalRandom$1] (valor [com.codahale.metrics.ThreadLocalRandom$1@39a33874]) y un valor del tipo [com.codahale.metrics.ThreadLocalRandom] (valor com.codahale.metrics.ThreadLocalRandom@acf653c]) pero no pudo quitarlo cuando la aplicación web se paró. Los hilos se van a renovar con el tiempo para intentar evitar in posible fallo de memoria.

org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent La biblioteca nativa de Apache Tomcat basada en ARP que permite un rendimiento óptimo en entornos de desarrollo no ha sido hallada en java.library.path:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib

15-Apr-2016 08:19:39.337 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars Al menos un JAR, que se ha explorado buscando TLDs, aún no contenía TLDs. Activar historial de depuración para este historiador para una completa lista de los JARs que fueron explorados y de los que nos se halló TLDs. Saltarse JARs no necesarios durante la exploración puede dar lugar a una mejora de tiempo significativa en el arranque y compilación de JSP .
```

Excuse for the spanish but I hope u know what are the issues cause the first 3 are kinda popular online.

I think the problem is on CAS-server but I'm not totally sure and the lack of information online its giving me headaches. We have configured CAS-server to deploy on startup (the only information I found about CAS was that its not hot deploy friendly) and I dunno what else to do.

If I use "pmap -x PID" with java gives me a big list that shows me most of the memory ocuppied in addresses with "[ anon ]" mapping. A lot of those addresses (dozens) require exactly 409592K and some of them even more (I can see 2097664K for example). All the big ones have "[ anon ]" as mapping and RW permissions.

Thank you for the help I'am more a IT tech than a code writer so I'm feeling out of my zone with this issues.

Comment: Profile it, find the problem, fix it (or have someone else fix it), profit.

Comment: Profile it how?  I can say its not heap size configuration (and yeah, I know Virtual Memory requirement its usually bigger than the heap size parameters we configure) but we have clearly something wrong and I cant understand where the problem is cause when I look for solutions to OOEM (had them too) its always topics about Tomcat where people says its a JVM thing. I appreciate the help anyway, thx.

Comment: You need a profiler (that's the easy part), and someone who can use it and understand the results. It looks like you'll be needing some outside help if you're not familiar with the code side.